# Get items back on toolbar

Tags: eclipse, toolbar

I have disabled an item in the Eclipse Luna (Service Release 1, 4.4.1) toolbar and now I can't get it back.

I have tried:

a) context menu / restore hidden toolbar entries

b) Window/Customize perspective.../Tool bar visibility

When I check the item in case b), it gives me the message

> Make Item Visible
>
> "New Wizards" cannot be made visible because it is in the unavailable "null" command group.
>
> Would you like to switch to the Command Group Availability tab?
>
> Yes   No

However, it does neither switch to the "Command Groups Availability" tab, nor can I find it there when I navigate to that tab manually.

This also applies to other items in the toolbar, not only to "New Wizards".

c) Window/Reset perspective...

This works after restarting Eclipse.

**Is there a way to get a toolbar item back without resetting the whole perspective?**